# which is an alternate chart for sankey diagram in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, sankey-diagram

I have been trying to visualise a sequence chart(flow) in tableau using sankey chart. is there any workaround for sankey? if there is an workaround suggest a good visualisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use heatmaps with source/ target in rows and columns and the flow value be represented in the cell.
Alternatively, you can stick with tableau for sankeys. I have done that and it adds immense value to develop overall storyline.